# Unit testing hybrid C++ / CLI / C# Code in Visual Studio fails

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, c++-cli

We have been given a C# DLL which contains code required for loading and manipulating a proprietary data format. Our codebase is primarily native C++. So we can access the supplied library, I wrote a DLL that consists of

- a native C++ wrapper class that implements the necessary API
- A C++/CLI bridge class that marshals data in and out and and delegates calls to the C# DLL.

I wrote a basic (native) C++ console application to test that the API does what I wanted. It did. I then wrote a (native, Microsoft Visual Studio) unit test project that calls the API. Surprisingly, it crashes with some unstated exception when constructing the interface object.

Some minimal code:

InteropAPI.h:

```
#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged

#if defined(INTEROP_API_EXPORTS)
#define INTEROP_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define INTEROP_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <string>

class InteropBridgeArchive;

struct InteropRecord
{
    std::string Name;
    int Id;
    std::string Data;
};

class INTEROP_API InteropAPI
{
public:
    InteropAPI();
    ~InteropAPI();

    InteropRecord GetRecord(int id) const;

private:
    InteropBridgeArchive * impl_;
};
```

InteropAPI.cpp:

```
#pragma managed
#include "InteropBridge.h"
#pragma unmanaged
#include "InteropAPI.h"

InteropAPI::InteropAPI()
: impl_(new InteropBridge())
{   
}

InteropAPI::~InteropAPI()
{
    delete impl_;
}

InteropRecord InteropAPI::GetRecord(const int id) const
{
    return impl_->GetRecord(id);
}
```

InteropBridge.h

```
#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged
#include "InteropAPI.h"

#pragma managed

#include <vcclr.h>

class InteropBridge
{
public:
    InteropArchive();
    InteropRecord GetRecord(System::Int32 id) const;

private:
    gcroot<InteropCSharpDll::Archive^> archive_;
};
```

InteropBridge.cpp:

```
#pragma unmanaged
#include <string>
#pragma managed
#include "InteropBridge.h"
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

InteropBridge::InteropBridge()
{
    archive_ = gcnew InteropCSharpDll::Archive;
}

InteropRecord InteropBridge::GetRecord(const System::Int32 id) const
{
    auto return_value = archive_->GetRecord(id);
    InteropRecord record;
    record.Name = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(return_value.Name);
    record.Id = return_value.Id;
    record.Data = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(return_value.Data);
    return record;
}
```

The test C# DLL has this:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace InteropCSharpDll
{
    public struct Record
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Id;
        public string Data;
    }

    public class Archive
    {
        public Record GetRecord(int id)
        {
            return _records.First(r => r.Id == id);
        }

        private readonly Record[] _records = 
        {
            new Record {Name = "Foo", Id = 0, Data = "Foo.Data"},
            new Record {Name = "Bar", Id = 2, Data = "Bar.Data"},
            new Record {Name = "Egg", Id = 7, Data = "Egg.Data"},
        };
    }
}
```

Clearly, if this hybrid structure can't be unit tested as native code, we can't test anything that touches it, so it's quite important to get to the bottom of why it crashes. This code runs nicely as a native C++ project:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "../InteropCppCliBridgeDll/InteropAPI.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "../x64/Debug/InteropCppCliBridgeDll.lib")

int main(int , char ** )
{
    const InteropAPI archive;
    const auto record = archive.GetRecord(0);
    std::cout << "Name: " << record.Name << "\n";
    std::cout << "Id: " << record.Id<< "\n";
    std::cout << "Data: " << record.Data<< "\n\n";
}
```

whereas in a native unit test project, the crash occurs in or around the line

```
archive_ = gcnew InteropCSharpDll::Archive;
```

Comment: Managed code likes throwing exceptions, you'll be blind as a bat when the exception isn't caught and makes it to the native code.  Debug with Project > Properties > Debugging > "Debugger type" = Mixed.  That enables both the native and the managed debugging engines, you can now see managed exceptions as well.  Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and tick "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" so the debugger breaks when the exception is thrown.  Not necessarily at identifiable code, a FileNotFoundException is pretty common when the jitter can't compile the code before it executes.

Comment: That's kinda helpful: I now see multiple exceptions: the first is 

System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Interop' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

and then

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'BoostTestAdapter.XmlSerializers, ... 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'GoogleTestAdapter.XmlSerializers, ... 

and then exit.

Comment: The XmlSerializer exceptions are normal, just the way XML serialization is implemented, BadImageFormat is your nemesis.  I won't risk a guess at how that could go wrong.

Comment: Visual Studio's Google Test runner does not seem to suffer from this problem, so I have moved my tests over to that. It's not a great solution, as the bulk of our test code is MSTEST. Still, better than nothing. Oh, and I've reported the issue to Microsoft.